# Structure of the EPO law

Tags: european, epo, epc

When I have to look at some rules or laws or the like from the [EPC](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/epc.html), I always struggle to navigate to the correct phrases. When I simply google for what I'm looking for I get there in seconds but I never do by navigating there on my own.

I guess this is caused by the fact that I don't understand the overall structure like when do I have to look at a **guideline**, or an **article**, or a **rule**.
Also, when I learn for EQE, in almost every answer there are multiple cross-references given which makes it quite hard to get the correct answer. From our national law, I'm used to combine usually two or maybe three paragraphs which, at least, are always given within the same law and also almost always within the same chapter.
But in EPC it seems so arbitrary to me, I don't get the structure of it.
Could you please shed some light on me?

Comment: This site works best when a question is specific. This seems a bit vague. In any case Google is helpful on many sites. I find things on Microsoft’s tech support site much easier using google instead of the built in tools.

Comment: It's probably not a right or yes question but I would say it's not really broad? However, what is Microsoft tech support? I guess Google is not providing proper search results (contact Microsoft support?)

Comment: The part of Microsoft’s website that provides documentation for their development tools like programming languages. For me hard to find anything I don’t already know without using Google.